# "all day and all night" or "all day and night"

Tags: quantifiers

can we re-write "all day and all night" to be "all day and night"

> No one speaks and the DVD player runs **all day and all night**. [Adventures in Europe and Central America](https://books.google.ae/books?id=XvHK2fkGrEAC&pg=PA380&dq=%22+all+day+and+all+night+%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%20all%20day%20and%20all%20night%20%22&f=false)

> No one speaks and the DVD player runs **all day and night**.

Comment: Usually, one says: all day and all  night. That is the idiom.

Comment: @Lambie - I must disagree; [they're both quite common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+day+and+night%2Call+day+and+all+night&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20day%20and%20night%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20day%20and%20all%20night%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @stangdon which is better to use with the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No one speaks and the DVD player runs all day and night.

That is not quite as clear as all day and all night, but probably would be understood.  On Edit: *all day and all night* is an idiom in common usage.

I'd suggest.

> No one speaks and the DVD player runs night and day.

*night and day* is a common idiom that means **continuously** (added On Edit.)

I can't tell you *why*, but this is far more clear than *all day and night.*.

Comment: The difference is not clarity. ***The difference between them is the context in which they would be used.*** One is a quasi-idiomatic expression whereas the other (all day and night) would be used in a technical or non-expressive, "non-poetic" context.